# Print the average of std::vector

Tags: c++, average, stdvector

As title suggests I'm trying to learn how to print out the average of a vector. Which can be done with:

```
int avgVec(const vector<int> & x)
{
   int sum=0;
   for(int i=0; i<x.size(); ++i)
    {
    sum+=x[i];//sets sum to vector size

    }
   return sum/x.size(); //Now calculates the average
}
```

Has this been set-up correctly?

Now the vector in question takes input from the user which should be set up as:

```
vector<int> myVec;
int i;
do
{
cin >> i;
myVec.push_back(i);
}while(i>0);
```

Has this also been set-up correctly?

Now in order for this to print the average would I go about making a print function or simply after doing:

```
avgVec(myVec);
```

I'd print out myVec, or have I gone about this in the wrong way? 
I've executed the code and it does in fact compute the average, but it only does the first number inputed, which makes the average 1.
I feel like I'm right there, but one part is just not clicking.

Comment: Your code computes the average rounded down to the nearest integer, is that as expected, or you need a fractional value?

Comment: This seems to be three questions, and I'm not sure which bit you're actually stuck on. What input did you give? What was the output? What did you expect?

Comment: @Gassa I do not need a fractional value, I would like it rounded down to the nearest integer.

Comment: @Useless I was expecting to compute the average inside the vector, but when I input a number, such as 4, it computes the average, and spits out one. It doesn't actually add anything together and then give me the average I was hoping for. I have a feeling it's doing as intended, but I'm missing something to get it to do what I actually want.

Comment: @ZachMarsh: Is it your intent that the average of 3 and 4 should be 3 exactly (that's what you get with integer arithmetic)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code snippet is wrong

```
vector<int> myVec;
int i;
do
{
cin >> i;
myVec.push_back(i);
}while(i>0);
```

because you will enter one non-positive number that is the last number of the vector will be non-positive.

The valid code would look as

```
vector<int> myVec;
int i;
while ( cin >> i && i > 0 ) myVec.push_back(i);
```

The function also is wrong because nothing prevents the vector to be empty. So I would write it the following way

```
int avgVec( const vector<int> & v )
{
   int sum = 0;

   for ( int x : v ) sum += x;

   return v.empty() ? 0 : sum / v.size();
}
```

Comment: Alright, thanks for the corrections, but when printing the actual average computed how would I go about doing that, because it definitely works, but I'm getting the same problem as before where when I enter, 4 for example, it spits out 1 rather than adding all the values in the vector together.

Comment: @Zach Marsh I have not understood what you mean saying that "when I enter, 4 for example, it spits out 1". What does it split?!

Comment: My apologies, what I meant by spits out 1, is that when I enter 4 it figures out the average and gives back 1. It doesn't actually add values in the vector together.

Comment: @ Zach Marsh I do not see ehere values are not added in the vector. The loop I wrote adds values to the vector.

Comment: @Zach Marsh By the way if you would enter only one value to the vector that is for example 4 then the average will be equal also to 4. So I do not understand totally what you are speaking about.

Answer (score 8):

use the C++ standard library:

```
double avgVec(std::vector<int> const&v) // note: the average must not be an integer
{
   return v.empty()? 0.0 :
          std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0)) / v.size();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The main problem with your code is that you're using **integer arithmetic**.

E.g. with integer arithmetic 7/3 → 2, with 1 as remainder.

Instead do e.g. `1.0*std::accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), 0 )/v.length()`, where the multiplication by `1.0` forces conversion to `double` (the default floating point type in C and C++), and return a `double`.

---

An alternative to multiplying by `1.0` is to use an explicit `static_cast`, which is more general but also more verbose.

Another alternative, less general but more elegant for this case, is to use `0.0` instead of integer `0` as the starting value for `std::accumulate`, as noted by [KitsuneYMG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86515/kitsuneymg) in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618213/print-the-average-of-stdvector/22618576#comment34442747_22618576). This works because the starting value determines the value type for the accumulation and its result.

---

Also, note that your current input code pushes the last non-positive input value on the stack, so if the user enters 0 as the last value, it will contribute to the count but not to the sum, thus reducing the average a bit…

Comment: There is no any problem with integer arithmetic. It depends only on what type of the result the author want to get.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I doubt that the integer “average” is intentional.

Comment: a more elegant way would be to provide `0.` as the initial condition to accumulate.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: oh yeah, I didn't notice, it determines the value type. thanks!

Comment: @ Cheers and hth. - Alf I do not see any intention of the author to get a float average. He says nothing about this.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Just a side note on `accumulate`. It's pretty darned useful for non-accumulation tasks. Either coupled with c++11 lambdas or boost's Phoenix library, it becomes very neat for executing a bunch of stuff and doing SOMETHING to the results. Like this: `accumulate( sinks.begin(), sinks.end(), 0, _1.sink( data ) | _2);` That calls sink on each member of sinks and bit-ors the return values together. If you're using the convention that sink()'s return is 0=success, !0=fail, then that will sorta "roll up" the results. I find "accumulate" to be a name that pidgin-holes the function.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing your own loop for summing up the vector, you should use `std::accumulate` (like Walter [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22619266/1593077)), but - don't pass a vector reference, even if it's just a `const`.

Let's take inspiration from `std::accumulate`'s interface:

```
template <class InputIt, class T>
T accumulate(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init);
```

And write something like:

```
template <typename InputIt, typename Result = double>
Result average(InputIt start, InputIt end)
{
    static_assert(
        std::is_arithmetic<std::decay_t<decltype(*start)>>::value,
        "Can only average arithmetic values");
    return static_cast<Result>(
        std::accumulate(start, end, static_cast<Result>(0)) / 
        std::distance(start, end)
    );
}
```

Notes:

- I don't like `first` and `last`, since `last` is not really the last, it's one past the last element; so I use `start` and `end` instead.
- If you were using C++20, you could constraint the templates themselves; and you could also consider [std::reduce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce) instead of `std::accumulate`.

And if you want a function to call for a container, write that too:

```
template <typename Container, typename Result = double>
Result average(const Container& c)
{
   using const_iter = typename Container::const_iterator;
   return average<const_iter, Result>(std::cbegin(c), std::cend(c));
}
```

... and if you're in C++20, you could instead write this for a range rather than an arbitrary type.

See this [running on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/41d66E4zG).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using zero to stop your input loop but still including it in the vector. This might be your intent, but it does affect the result.

Answer (score -1):

Idiomatic C++ is:

```
int avgVec(const std::vector<int> & x)
{
   int sum = 0;

   for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++it)
      sum += *it;

   return sum / x.size();
}
```

Comment: The range based for statement is not an "idiomatic C++", is it?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, the advantage of this code is that you can substitute any of the "sequence" type containers. Using C++11 you could even restrict the changes to the header of the function...

Comment: And what is the problem with the range based for statement?

Comment: With teh same success I can use the range based for statement with  std::list.

Comment: What happens if x.size() is 0 ?

Comment: It's not idiomatic to pass references to `std::vector`, to functions which don't rely on their input being an `std::vector`.